# Cypress - Unable to run multiple tests

Tags: cypress

I am very new to cypress automation and have been following though some examples and have ran into an issue that does not appear to be addressed in any video I have seen, where multiple tests in the same 'describe' do not run as expected.

If I create the following code & run it, it all works perfectly:-

```
describe('My First Test', () => {
    it('Open Google', () => {
        cy.visit('https://google.co.uk')
        cy.get('#L2AGLb > .QS5gu').click()
        cy.get('.gLFyf').type('Automation Step by Step{Enter}')
    })
})
```

I have then attempted to split up the test into individual tests, as follows:-

```
describe('My First Test', () => {
    it('Open Google', () => {
        cy.visit('https://google.co.uk')     
    })

    it('Confirm warning', () => {
        cy.get('#L2AGLb > .QS5gu').click()
        cy.get('.gLFyf').type('Automation Step by Step{Enter}')
    })

    
    it('Confirm warning', () => {
        cy.get('.gLFyf').type('Automation Step by Step{Enter}')
    })
})
```

The problem now is that after opening Chrome and then going into the next test, which should allow me to type the text, a 'default blank page' is displayed and the tests then fail.

What am I missing here to be able to run these three tests fully?

[Code in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al7Fq.png)

[Error after opening Chrome & attempting to type in box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxgbd.png)

As above really, I was hoping to be able to run all three simple tests together.

**EDIT - I rolled back my version of Cypress to 10.10.0 and it works perfectly, so no idea what has changed on the latest version released yesterday.**

Answer (score 3):

Try it with [Test Isolation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation) turned to `false`.

> **Best Practice:** Tests should always be able to be run independently from one another **and still pass**

This was added in Cypress 12.0.0.

But if you want to play without it,

[Test Isolation Disabled](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation)

| testIsolation | beforeEach test |
| --- | --- |
| true | - clears page by visiting about:blank |
|  | - clears cookies in all domains |
|  | - local storage in all domains |
|  | - session storage in all domains |
| false | **does not alter the current browser context** |

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    testIsolation: false,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should visit your page for every test. You can put the cy.visit in a  [beforeEach](https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-before-beforeeach-after-aftereach) function.